# Highcharts: Highstock range using lazy loader

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to use lazy loader to dynamically select ranges.
The database it is using is quite large, many years of data with minute intervals.
Here is the fiddle example from highstock: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/ZLswj/

I altered the SQL query and converted it to MySQL PHP PDO.

The problem is that the startdate in the graph is always 1970 - to the date that is set:

```
data = [].concat(data, [[Date.UTC(2011, 9, 14, 19, 59), null, null, null, null]]);
```

How can i make the graph start at the 1st of january of 2014?

PHP script

```
$range = $end - $start;
$startTime = gmstrftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', $start / 1000);
$endTime = gmstrftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', $end / 1000);

//echo $startTime;
//echo $endTime;
$sq = $db->query("SELECT unix_timestamp(time) * 1000 as datetime, temp_out FROM archive      WHERE time between '$startTime' AND '$endTime'");
```

The time column is of type "datetime"..

Tried:

```
data = [].concat(data, [[null, null, null, null, Date.UTC(2014, 7, 15, 12, 00)]]);
```

Start year is still 1970...

Also, is it possible to have highstock go back in time using the range selector?

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle with some random/static data? Looks like your timestamps is string, not a number.

Comment: I really wished i could, the php side of the script seems to work fine, it's just the javascript that does only send the stop date? start = 1970.. when i run the JS above in fiddle with my php json datasource the chrome tab crashes (probably too much data)

Comment: How about simplified demo? Not with all data, just a couple of first points.

Comment: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/samples/data/from-sql.php here is the PHP file i changed it to MySQL PDO. JSfiddle will work.

Comment: And link to jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/ZLswj/

Comment: Let me explain again: I need live demo **with** issue. Not PHP file or Highcharts demo :) Or at least show how your data looks like (edit question) after receiving from PHP.